# How to pass custom header from NGINX Reverse Proxy to SockJs websocket connection in the server?

Tags: websocket, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy. Below are the setings in nginx.conf file. I want to pass a custom header from the proxy to the back-end HTTP server. I do get the custom header in the HTTP server but I am not getting it in my sockJs connection.

```
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-RealIPRemote $realip_remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-RemoteAddr $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header mycustomhdr customname;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:18000;

   # WebSocket support
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header mycustomhdr customname;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

In the http server to which the connection is proxied to:

```
sockServer = sockJs.createServer(
... 
 sockServer.on('connection', function (conn) {
      console.log("conn.headers")
      console.log(conn.headers)
```

Here is what I get:

```
{ 'x-forwarded-for': '192.168.1.222',
        'x-real-ip': '192.168.1.222',
               host: 'example.com',
       'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.117 Safari/537.36',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' }
```

I am not getting the custom header **mycustomhdr**.

~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you won't. You'll notice several of your other headers are missing too. Not all headers are exposed.

From [the docs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node/blob/master/README.md):

> headers (object) Hash containing various headers copied from last
>   receiving request on that connection. Exposed headers include:
>   `origin`, `referer` and `x-forwarded-for` (and friends). We explicitly
>   do not grant access to `cookie` header, as using it may easily lead to
>   security issues (for details read the section "Authorisation").

Comment: I got around it!  I set x-forwarded-for to the custom header I need nginx to pass. I am not using x-forwarded-for, the real value. May be I should use referer.. does not matter but all exposed headers are not used by the application server so one of them can be used (or abused!).  Do you foresee any problem or side effects? Thanks

Comment: Nice hack  It's a non standard header used to preserve client ip through a reverse proxy, if you don't need it for that then I don't see why you will have any issues setting it to whatever you want.

Comment: @minik Now I think that a  better hack will be to piggy back on that header so both values are available. After all the application server knows the hack and interpret the header as actually consisting of two values!